# No fields in schema - will not index - Sphinx

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I am using Sphinx, I have successfully built indexes with simpler queries but when I added the `COALESCE` and `AS` MySQL keywords to my query, I am getting the error "**No fields in schema - will not index**". I want to add attributes so I don't have to query the database for id match details, thought it would be a little faster, if I use sql_field_string in place of sql_attr_string I no longer get the error and the index builds but it takes triple the time to build.

```
SELECT r.RegistrationId, coalesce(CampaignID,'') as CampaignId, coalesce(FirstName,'') as FirstName, coalesce(LastName,'') as LastName, \
        coalesce(Address1,'') as Address1, coalesce(Address2,'') as Address2, coalesce(City,'') as City, coalesce(State,'') as State, \
        coalesce(Zip,'') as Zip,coalesce(Email,'') as Email, coalesce(Phone,'') as Phone,coalesce(Affiliate,'') as Affiliate, \
        coalesce(SubAffiliate,'') as SubAffiliate \
        FROM Registration r WHERE r.CreateDT >= '2013-01-01'
        sql_attr_string = CampaignId
        sql_attr_string = FirstName
        sql_attr_string = LastName
        sql_attr_string = Address1
        sql_attr_string = Address2
        sql_attr_string = City
        sql_attr_string = State
        sql_attr_string = Zip
        sql_attr_string = Email
        sql_attr_string = Phone
        sql_attr_string = Affiliate
        sql_attr_string = SubAffiliate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An index NEEDS at least one field to function. That's non negotiable.

If you really dont want to have any fields, could just make a fake one.

...,'a' as fake,...

or similar. Which wont take very long to index.

Comment: `source employee_src
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = sphinx
    sql_pass        = sphinx123
    sql_db          = test
    sql_port        = 3306
    sql_query       = SELECT id, city, info FROM employees
    sql_attr_uint = id
    sql_attr_string = city
    sql_attr_json = info

}` the info field is of type JSON in MySQL 5.7 whenever I run ./indexer --all --rotate i am getting error no fields in schema will not index.

Comment: That index only contains **attributes**. You've defined all the columns as attributes. Your 'info' is an attribute, **not** an field.  you NEED at least one field. No way round that.

Comment: info is also a field it contains JSON data and also it is type of JSON which is introduced in MySQL 5.7

Comment: Its still not a field as far as **Sphinx** is concerned. 'sql_attr_json' makes an attribute **only**, not any fields. Read up on fields and attributes in sphinx. They have very specific meanings. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#fields

Comment: i am having table with 2 columns id and another is a text column contains json data, to query the fields of the json string I have to index the column twice such as: `sql_query       = SELECT id, parts_jsn FROM parts_data
    sql_attr_uint = id
    sql_field_string = parts_jsn
    sql_attr_json = j` could you please tell me it is the right way to do that ?